# is i an element of $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt[4]{2})$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I am trying to see if the polynomial $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible in the field $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt[4]{2})$.

I understand that it's only irreducible if it has linear factors as it's of degree $2$, and the roots are $i$ and $-i$. However I'm not sure if these roots lie in my field.

is the field $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt[4]{2}) = \{a + bi\sqrt[4]{2} : a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ or are there other terms I need to consider? I know that if it's of this form then i is not included, but how do I know if there aren't any other terms?

Comment: Note that $(i\sqrt[3]{2})^3=-2i$

Comment: Hint: find an embedding of your number field in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If $i$ were in that field then $a=2^{1/4}$ would also be in that field and thus $\mathbb {Q} \subset \mathbb {Q} (a) \subseteq \mathbb {Q} (i2^{1/4})$. Do you see that this would lead to a contradiction as the last two fields in the above containment relation would be same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is the ring of polynomials of indeterminate $x$ with co-efficients in $\mathbb{Q}$. So, $\mathbb{Q}[i\sqrt[4]{2}]$ is \begin{align*}\{a+bi\sqrt[4]{2}+c\left(i\sqrt[4]{2}\right)^2+d\left(i\sqrt[4]{2}\right)^3+e\left(i\sqrt[4]{2}\right)^4:a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{Q}\}=\{a+bi\sqrt[4]{2}-c\sqrt{2}-di\sqrt[4]{8}:a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}\}\end{align*} because every degree of $i\sqrt[4]{2}$ higher than $4$ can be expressed as multiples of one of $i\sqrt[4]{2},-\sqrt{2},-i\sqrt[4]{8},1$. Since $i$ cannot be expressed as $a+bi\sqrt[4]{2}-c\sqrt{2}-di\sqrt[4]{8}$ if $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}$, $x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[i\sqrt[4]{2}]$.

Comment: That makes, sense. Thank you!

Comment: Your last statement "since $i$ can't be expressed as..." needs some more justification and in fact that is the crux of the problem.